# How to handle "No module name found" in django url

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-urls, django-apps

Suppose I have an django application which doesn't exist or is not included in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

How to handle such an error? And at exactly what point in the flow is this error occurring?

I want to redirect the user to 404 page if such an error has occurred.

Comment: If an app is missing or not included in `INSTALLED_APPS` that suggests a problem with the configuration of the overall project and returning a 404 error probably isn't appropriate. Can you explain in which cases an application might be missing?

Comment: suppose i am having a certain set of apps which are optional, but in main url.py, reference to those app are included.

Comment: Are you pointing to the urls.py in your settings.py?

Comment: yes, to the main url.py, in home directory of project  and then passing the flow to individual App.urls